# SharePoint Hosted App - Error when calling load on ClientContext for other sitecollection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

im using JSOM. When calling the following code

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostweburl);
var site = appContextSite.get_site();
ctx.load(site);
```

When using the hostweburl it works.
But when calling an other url from an other sitecollection I'm getting an Unauthorized error.

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

Comment: Guessing you have already found this resource http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, good article but doesn't work. I've also tried it with REST API.

Comment: And creating a new context with var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl); does nothing?

Comment: Doesn't work either. While creating the ClientContext I'm getting an error from sp.js Error: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'set_formDigestHandlingEnabled'

Comment: Yep ditto @SteffenSchindler.all I am getting is Object doesn't support property or method Set_formDigestHandlingEnabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think that this is impossible. My solution in this case is that I'm going to use the search. Because I only must read some lists I'm using the Managed Property Path.